# when i use const { myCardStyle } = this.myStyles; at the class below it shows error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm learning react native. in my application, for one of the components, when i use `this.` at `const { myCardStyle } = this.myStyles;` at the class below it shows error: `Possible unhandled Promise Rejection ...`, but when i put it without `this` it works.

```
const Card = (myProps) => {

const { myCardStyle } = myStyles;
console.log(8 + myProps.children);
  return(
    <View style={myCardStyle}>
      {myProps.children}
    </View>
  );

};

const myStyles = {
  myCardStyle: {
     blabla
  }
};
```

Comment: this will work only inside the class or functions that aare binded. u can access const without usng this keyword.

Comment: could you add more info and make it as an answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`const` can be accessed without the help of `this` keyword. Look at the example below. styles can be accessed globally by the class without using this keyword.

`this` keyword is used when we want to access state or prop objects that are binded to the class. Normally u can bind the finctions using `bind` keyword

/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class VideoExample extends Component {
 __click(){
    //if u want to access this keyword here 
    //u have to bind this function
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text onPresss={this._click.bind(this)}/>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('VideoExample', () => VideoExample);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move const myStyle inside Card method and before 
const { myCardStyle } = myStyles

```
const Card = (myProps) => {
  const myStyles = {
    myCardStyle: {
       blabla
    }
  };

  const { myCardStyle } = myStyles;
  console.log(8 + myProps.children);
  return(
    <View style={myCardStyle}>
      {myProps.children}
    </View>
  );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

styles are defined outside the class VideoExample so you can't access it using the this.myStyles. 
You can directly refer the variable by it's name and if you want to access it in another class you can access it by VideoExample.myStyles.